# How to close a project in Android Studio?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

How I closed a project in Android Studio like a close a project in workspace Eclipse?

Comment: I think a better convention is to create separate installations for each project, that only if you're projects aren't using each other. In that case you shouldn't close them anyways.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I think it's a legible question, because in Eclipse is a very helpful functionality.

In Android Studio:

File -> Close Project

Answer (score -2):

In android studio(3.0.1), File -> Open Recent -> Manage Projects -> click on 'X' for the project you wish to close. Now if you want to delete the project, go to the project location and delete it.

Comment: That looks like the accepted answer for a more than four year old question. Anything new you want to share?